# For finite field $F$ where char($F$) = p, how is $\mathbb{F}_p$ not an isomorphism to $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite field where $char(F) = p$. I encountered the following preposition in my textbook (given the stated conditions): "We have an injective homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{F}_p \longrightarrow F$." My question: why is this $\varphi$ not an isomorphism? Since all finite fields of order $n$ (where $n$ is prime) are isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_n$, I don't see how our $\varphi$ would behave any differently (I suspect I have a misunderstanding of $char(F)$, but I'm not sure what it is).

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to believe that finite fields can only have a prime number of elements. This is not true.

Consider the field $\mathbb{F}_3$ and the polynomial $X^2+1$. Since this polynomial has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_3$, it is irreducible and so the ideal $I$ it generates in $\mathbb{F}_3[X]$ is maximal.

Thus, by general theory, $F=\mathbb{F}_3[X]/I$ is a field and $\mathbb{F}_3$ embeds in it, so $F$ obviously has characteristic $3$. And it has $3^2=9$ elements.

On the contrary, the *Frobenius endomorphism* over the finite field $F$ with characteristic $p$ defined by $a\mapsto a^p$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

Note that if $char(F) = p$, this does not imply that $|F| = p$. Rather, it implies that $|F|=p^k$ for some $k$.

Answer (score 0):

A finite field of characteristic $p$ is a set of roots of the polynomial $X^{p^n} - X$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ for some $n \geq 1$. These roots must always be distinct, which is why the field has $p^n$ elements and is denoted by $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. This implies that $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ itself is always a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, because any $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$ satisfies $x^{p^n} = x$ for any $n \geq 1$. You might also be interested to know that the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is an *infinite* field of characteristic $p$, and is given by $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Hence, a field of characteristic $p$ need not even be finite.